# Why is this SQL Injection attempt failing on DVWA?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, dvwa

I'm practicing SQL injection on DVWA (non-blind) with the lowest security settings. I want to list the tables in the current database. To do that, I attempt to enter 0'; show tables;-- in the User ID field like this

[image]

I expect that would issue the following statement to MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '0'; show tables;--'
```

However, when I hit submit I get this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show tables;--'' at line 1
```

I suspect its something simple I'm missing and would appreciate any help in learning the correct way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: The MySQL driver probably doesn’t allow sending multiple statements at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can check the source below for the full scenario

Source : https://computersecuritystudent.com/SECURITY_TOOLS/DVWA/DVWAv107/lesson6/index.html

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here. To improve your answer, you should include the relevant information in it.